# elasticsearch change field type mapping to nested

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to change an elasticsearch field to nested, I'm having problems with the command to do this.
I'm not sure if it's because it's a couple of fields down that is giving me grief.

Here's what I'm trying to input:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_mapping/data' -d '
{
"data" : {
    "properties" : {
        "parsed" : {
            "properties" : {
                "PMSetup" : {
                    "properties" : {
                        "Result" : {
                          "type" : "nested"
                          "include_in_parent" : true
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}   
}
'
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not possible to change mapping of an existing field. Please refer to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

Mapping cannot be updated for existing fields. The only thing you can do is `DELETE` your index and then `PUT` it back and `POST` mapping all over again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Elastic Team, please invent one "ALTER TABLE"!!!